# $P_n T P_nh$ tends to $Th$ as $n$ tends to infinity in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto an orthonormal basis of $H$. If $T$ be a bounded linear operator on $H$ , then does $P_nTP_nh\to Th$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

I think yes, by the completeness of hilbert space. But, is there a rigorous proof of the assertion?Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What exactly is $P_n$? I imagine that there is a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$, and $P_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by the first $n$ vectors. In that case $P_n\rightarrow I$, so your limit follows.

Comment: @Ehsaan yes, the space is separable, and thanks to your suggestion, the proof is immediate. So this does not require completeness and may be true in any inner product space, I think?

Comment: I guess you need completeness to define about the orthogonal projection. Check the "unique closest point theorem" that is used to define orthogonal projections in a Hilbert space.

Comment: As Ehsaan says, completeness is crucial in the proof of the unique closest point theorem.